# How to import object array from another js file on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, socket.io

**Hello Everyone!**
I wanna create object array with datas that comes from user.So I made something like that ;

***index.js***

```
var create_users = require("./createusers.js");
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('all_left_datas', ({name,role,players}) => {

    var roomCode = genRoomCode.generate({length:4,numbers:true});
    create_users.createUser(roomCode,name,role,socket.id);

socket.join(roomCode);


if(io.sockets.in(roomCode)) {
   console.log(create_users.users[socket.id].name + ' joined the room');
    io.emit('userNames', name); }
```

***createusers.js***

```
module.exports.users = {};

  module.exports = {
    createUser: function(roomCode,name,role,socketID) {
    module.exports.users[socketID] = {
    roomCode: roomCode,
    name: name,
    role: role,
    userID: socketID
  };
} };
```

But when I try to use it I am getting that error ;
**TypeError: Cannot set property '_aEg_PDxugjTMxZHAAAD' of undefined**
What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You're *overwriting* the original definition of the `users` object when you assign to `module.exports` again. What used to exist in `module.exports` gets discarded when something else is assigned to it. You need:

```
// createusers.js
module.exports = {
    users: {},
    createUser: function (roomCode, name, role, socketID) {
        module.exports.users[socketID] = {
            roomCode: roomCode,
            name: name,
            role: role,
            userID: socketID
        };
    }
};
```

You could also consider using modern syntax and shorthand properties to make the code a bit more concise:

```
createUser(roomCode, name, role, userID) {
    module.exports.users[userID] = { roomCode, name, role, userID };
}
```

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem but I have another now.I am trying to use that array on socket.on('disconnect', (socket) => {
var roomCode = create_users.users[socket.id].roomCode; ... }); but I got that error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'roomCode' of undefined".